# org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: File is not writable: Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In **Spring Boot Batch** project, I am getting the below error, not sure what is wrong going on here ?

I am simply reading table from the mysql DB and writing it to the file using the FlatFileItemWriter. Also using the Partiontioner to read the code and write it to the Flat Files. `Spring Boot Parent` version `2.0.2.RELEASE`.

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: File is not writable: [C:\Spring_Learning\spring-batch\spring-batch-classic-db\csv\outputs\users.processed201-250.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.setUpOutputFile(FileUtils.java:88) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$OutputState.initializeBufferedWriter(FlatFileItemWriter.java:572) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$OutputState.access$000(FlatFileItemWriter.java:414) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.doOpen(FlatFileItemWriter.java:348) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter.open(FlatFileItemWriter.java:338) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bd919dcd.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d3ba3d4f.open(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197) ~[spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:139) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:136) [spring-batch-core-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Code

```
@Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Payments> slaveWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}") final String fromId,
            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}") final String toId) {

        FlatFileItemWriter<Payments> reader = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/outputs/users.processed" + fromId + "-" + toId + ".csv"));
        reader.setAppendAllowed(true);

        reader.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<Payments>() {
            {
                setDelimiter(",");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Payments>() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "customerNumber", "checkNumber", "paymentDate", "amount"});
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return reader;
    }
```

Comment: have you tried to change the path of the output file?

Comment: Try to write to another location and see if you get the same error. If not, then you have to make sure that the java process running your spring batch job has the rights to write to that location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to update your code :

```
FlatFileItemWriter<Payments> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/outputs/users.processed" + fromId + "-" + toId + ".csv"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
```

To :

```
FlatFileItemWriter<Payments> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/outputs/users.processed" + fromId + "-" + toId + ".csv"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
        writer.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
        writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);
```

I had the same error, it works for me.

For the details, it was because of the `restarted`argument of `FileUtils.setUpOutputFile(File file, boolean restarted, boolean append, boolean overwriteOutputFile)` which can be set to `true` when the job is restarted. A file is recovered from an old context and it's not writable...
I don't know why precisely.

Comment: No matter how hard I try - I always get this error message if setAppendAllowed is set as false: org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Output file was not created. So in order to create a new file I had to do this:  PrintWriter pwriter;
  try {
   pwriter = new PrintWriter(FILENAME);
   pwriter.print("");
   pwriter.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

Answer (score 0):

The exception from

```
if (!file.canWrite()) {
            throw new ItemStreamException("File is not writable: [" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "]");
}
```

**The File.canWrite as below**
So please check the path including parents as well if they all have "write" access

```
/**
 138:    * This method test whether or not the current thread is allowed to
 139:    * write to this object.  This will be true if and only if 1) The
 140:    * <code>SecurityManager</code> (if any) allows write access to the
 141:    * file and 2) The file exists and 3) The file is writable.  To determine
 142:    * whether or not a non-existent file can be created, check the parent
 143:    * directory for write access.
 144:    *
 145:    * @return <code>true</code> if writing is allowed, <code>false</code> 
 146:    * otherwise
 147:    *
 148:    * @exception SecurityException If the <code>SecurityManager</code> 
 149:    * does not allow access to the file
 150:    */
 151:   public boolean canWrite()
 152:   {
 153:     // First do a SecurityCheck before doing anything else.
 154:     checkWrite();
 155:      
 156:     // Test for existence.  This is required by the spec
 157:     if (! VMFile.exists(path))
 158:       return false;
 159: 
 160:     if (VMFile.isDirectory(path))
 161:       return VMFile.canWriteDirectory(this);
 162:     else
 163:       return VMFile.canWrite(path);
 164:   }
```

Comment: I have the same error as Prateek. The code you are showing is not the same as I have (see [source code](http://book2s.com/java/src/package/java/io/file.html#9187021f3e9f345a9b837b1573dfad28)). It appears that `isInvalid()` returns `true` (See [Source code](http://book2s.com/java/src/package/java/io/file.html#f536e8a50d5f73e242813145fb880a51)). I don't know why ...

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. It happens sometimes when the job is restarted. I will published an answer...